# long, single page site opens at mid-page instead of at the top

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a long, single page website with sections contained within `<div id="#">`. Currently, the site loads/opens near the bottom between `#services` and `#contact`. How can I have the page always load at the top when the URL is input directly, or when clicking on a link?

[Live site.](http://frshstudio.com)

Comment: Have you tried disabling all your JavaScripts to see if it could be one of them causing the jump?

Comment: This probably isn't causing your issue, but `#` isn't a valid character for the `id` attribute. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)

Comment: @fuzic I'm aware; I used `#` in this instance as a placeholder instead of listing out all of my divs. If you take a look at my code, you'll see this to be the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with your `<div id="#">`s. The reason your site doesn't start at the top is because of your contactform. Your name input field has `autofocus="autofocus"`, when something is focussed the browser will scroll to this position.

Just change

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="" placeholder="NAME" required="required" autofocus="autofocus">
```

in

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="" placeholder="NAME" required="required">
```

Answer (score 5):

It is because you have the autofocus attribute set (like so: `autofocus="autofocus"`) on your name input in the contact section near the bottom of the page.